# Trying to get data from merge helper function with Apollo Client InMemoryCache Object, but receive only ref property

Tags: javascript, apollo, apollo-client, in-memory-cache

I'm trying get a new set data from a paginated-like API I created but I only receive the object with the ref property from the cache, but the data from the api. How can I return a array of the existing and incoming data?

[InMemoryCache Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Gyn.png)

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  ssrMode: typeof window === undefined,
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache({
    typePolicies: {
      Query: {
        fields: {
          todos: {
            merge(existing, incoming) {
              console.log(incoming) // I want the data, not the ref object
              return [ ...existing, ...incoming ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
});
```

photos of the result in console log
[Result of the Merge Helper Function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLyxa.png)

[useQuery Hook calling the pagination api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjhPS.png)

if needed I left my repo below

[todo client git repo with merge helper function issue](https://github.com/rjointer2/todo_client.git)

Comment: Please post your code as [text with syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), not links to paintings of it. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: Thank you, I  went ahead and update my question, and links are just images but syntax is there now.

Comment: "*How can I return a array of the existing and incoming data?*" - why would you want to do that? The `merge` function is **supposed** to return an array of references.

Answer (score 2):

You have access to the cache in the third argument to `merge`, and you can use that to convert the references to data objects.

```
// assuming these are all the fields on your 
// Todo item's schema
const todoFragment = gql`
fragment todo on Todo {
  id
  name
  completed
}
`;

function merge(existing, incoming, { isReference, cache, variables }) {
  return [
    ...existing ?? [],
    ...incoming.map(x => {
      if (!isReference(x))
        return x; // it's already a data object
      else {
        // convert the Reference to a data object
        return cache.readFragment({
          fragment: todoFragment, // use a fragment with all properties on todo
          id: options.cache.identify(x),
          // only relevant if the objects' fields use variables
          variables,
        });
      }
    }),
  ];
}
```